# confused about this javascript closure pattern

Tags: javascript, closures

```
h = function(){
    x = function(){
        alert("try");
    }();
    x;
};
```

I'm confused about this behavior: the inner function is immediately invoked, and it's ok. But why i must have an assignment? Why i can't write it anonymously?

Comment: the last line, is for debug purposes, and i find variable undefined.  why i must assign to a variable an immediately executed function?  if I do not, i have a syntax error, but the variable remains undefined.

Comment: What are you even trying to do here?

Comment: nothing, i'm just reading "javascript - the good parts" and i'm doing some testing.

Comment: but why two downvote? without any words? it's stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I added a var and moved the internal execution down a line

```
h = function(){
    var x = function(){
        alert("try");
    };
    x();
};
```

then you can invoke h

```
h();
```

or you can invoke it directly with

```
h = function(){
    var x = function(){
        alert("try");
    };
    x();
}();
```

or you can twist it into the module pattern with

```
h = function(){
    var x = function(){
        alert("try");
    };
    return {
        x:x
    };
};

h().x();
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can write it anonymously, of course:

```
(function(){
    (function(){
        alert("try");
    })();
}) ();
```

In fact, your example is not working, since you forgot to invoke it in the last line:

```
} ();
```

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24ys718q/)

Comment: Thank you naeramarth7, i omitted the invoking line, on onload i had h(); But your example is very exhaustive, thank you. I rest amazed about the x variable that in my example was required, and it remains undefined..